# The transformation OLEDB command is unsuccessful under insert query

Tags: ssis

In SSIS, using OLE DB command and moved in to another step column
mapping "it is showing only name else blank and i have to map all four column through insert under OLE DB command , even i can share error with this blog.I am using  MS BI and SQL-2008 R2 version.Kindly help me out.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking but as a general rule, for an Insert in an SSIS data flow, use the `OLE DB Destination` and not the `OLE DB Command`

Comment: Yeah I don't understand the question at all.  Can you get a native english-speaker to help you re-write it?   It doesn't make any sense.